# How to Avoid this Out of Memory Error when Generating Multiple Strings?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, out-of-memory, rdd

I'm working on a benchmarking task, and I need to generate millions of rows of event json.

Here is my sample code:

```
def generateEntry() = {
 s"""
    |{
    | "memberId": ${java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString},
    | "first_name": ${nameRandomizer},
    | "last_name": ${nameRandomizer
    |}""".stripMargin
}

// Generate 1000000 rows of Json String with fields: memberId, first_name, last_name
val entryList = mutable.ListBuffer[String]()
for (_ <- 1 to 1000000) {
 entryList += generateEntry()
}

val inputRDD: RDD[String] = sc.parallelize(entryList.result())
```

However this is causing an error:

```
Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
    at scala.StringContext.standardInterpolator(StringContext.scala:126)
    at scala.StringContext.s(StringContext.scala:95)
```

I am coding in spark by the way. I tried doing this by batch, but error still seem to occur. Please let me know, or provide sample code that I can use as a guide to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: You have either too many strings or too few memory. Gotta either decrease one or increase the other. Also, don't use mutable structures. They are evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List buffer is not needed. You can just map a Spark range to your function:

```
val inputRDD: RDD[String] = spark.range(1000000).rdd.map(x => generateEntry())
```

Comment: Didn't solve the problem though. But thanks!

Comment: this line alone should have been lazily evaluated and shouldn't cause OOM errors. Did the error come from somewhere else?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm taking my comment back. It did help to reduce the possibility of getting an OOM. I just found out that there's another list buffer present in my code and after removing them, I was able to run without OOM. Marking this as a helpful answer. Thank you!